# Activity will not start after ACTION_SCREEN_ON is received

Tags: android

I am creating a Lock Replacement application which obviously requires it to have an activity that starts the ACTION_SCREEN_ON is called. These are the portions of my code relevant to it:

```
public class StartupBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startupIntent = new Intent(context, Lockdown.class); // substitute with your launcher class
    startupIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(startupIntent);
}
```

}

Since ACTION_SCREEN_ON cannot be called from the Manifest I registered it dynamically in my main activity.

This is in my onCreate function of my main class (Lockdown)

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new StartupBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: But your IntentFilter will only be registered once the user has started your Activity manually, and it will be de-registered once your Activity pauses -- logcat may well warn that you've leaked a receiver instance.

Comment: Or maybe I don't understand in quite which situation SCREEN_ON is fired. :)  Anyway, you could also try adding CATEGORY_DEFAULT to your filter. You can also check logcat to see if you're missing a permission.

Comment: My receiver does work, I've added a Toast notification to see if it does alert my receiver when the screen comes on and it does, it may be a permission, I'll have to take a look at this.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your question (I was tired and on a train ;)). Anyway, if you're successfully receiving the `Intent` via your receiver, then there shouldn't be any permission problem. Your new activity code looks fine too, so I'm confused! Are there any `ActivityManager` or similar `Intent`-related entries in logcat when `context.startActivity(startupIntent)` gets called?

Comment: I noticed something when I disabled the Keyguard and if I am inside of my application and turn the Screen On and Off, my Toast notification pops up and then a second later my application starts the activity. What could be causing it to not start when on the phone is on another application or when the home screen is displayed? Would creating a service help solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this problem:

Adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` to the manifest of your main activity. You also have to add this flag to the receiver `startupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);`

Comment: In 2014 on 4.4.2 this still worked well for me, but only after I register the 2nd activity in the manifest with a <activity android:name=".Lockdown"></activity>